# Laravel filesystem, How to set public file only can view by after login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Laravel 5.7
PHP 7.2
DB mysql

already see https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem
I am using the Local Driver.

after some process, I have set a image to public file.
e.g.
https://127.0.0.1/storage/myViewFile/0120020301-3.png

I want to set only can view dir "myView File" after login.

How can I do it? thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Route::get('/storage/files/{file}', 'FilesController@show')->middleware('auth');`

and in the `show` method display the image.

Comment: how to display the image in show method? or you mean return the image path? Can you explain? thanks.

Comment: @OsamaKhalid I think there are a few options you can put it in `blade` and style it. or a `File response` eg. `return response()->file($pathToFile);`.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use your local driver and would want to make files accessible in your storage folder then you would run an artisan command like below

```
php artisan storage:link
```

This will ensure that files are accessible publicly as `example.com/public/storage/whateverfile`. However, if you want the files to be only accessible to authenticated user then may be you can put the files in `storage/myViewFile` which will make sure that files in the folder aren't publicly accessible. Then using a controller with an auth middleware or route with middleware you can make files accessible

Comment: And how would you make them available in a controller?  When you call `->download()` it tries to download from `public/`